# I'd like to make this powershell work in Windows 7 (with an appropriate substitution for Get-NetConnectionProfile)

Tags: powershell, network-programming, windows-7

I have this script that works in Windows 10+ but I need it to also work in Windows 7.

```
$Adapters=Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ?{$_.Status -eq "Up"} 
$IPAddresses=@()
$Profiles=@()
foreach ($Adapter in $Adapters)
{
    $IPaddresses+=Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $($Adapter.InterfaceIndex) -AddressFamily IPv4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Profiles+=Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $($Adapter.InterfaceIndex) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
$Domain = $IPAddresses | ? {$_.InterfaceIndex -eq ($Profiles | ? {$_.NetworkCategory -eq "DomainAuthenticated"}|select InterfaceIndex -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex)}
$Public = $IPAddresses | ? {$_.InterfaceIndex -eq ($Profiles | ? {$_.NetworkCategory -eq "Public"}|select InterfaceIndex -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex)}
if (($Domain -ne $null) -and ($Public -ne $null))
{
    Write-Host "Public Interface found on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
}
else {Write-Host "None"}
```

The goal is to test if I have a DomainAuthenticated Network connection and then to return the hostname of the machine IF there is ALSO an active PUBLIC network connection.  The problem is that [Get-NetworkConnectionProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/get-netconnectionprofile?view=windowsserver2019-ps) is only available in OSs ABOVE W7.

What is the pre-W10 equivalent to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - this appears to be the solution that I was looking for.  If anyone sees anything glaringly wrong, just shout out!

```
$OSVer = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version

if ($OSVer -like "10*") {

    $Adapters = Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_.Status -eq "Up" } 
    $IPAddresses = @()
    $Profiles = @()
    foreach ($Adapter in $Adapters) {
        $IPaddresses += Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $($Adapter.InterfaceIndex) -AddressFamily IPv4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Profiles += Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $($Adapter.InterfaceIndex) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    $Domain = $IPAddresses | ? { $_.InterfaceIndex -eq ($Profiles | ? { $_.NetworkCategory -eq "DomainAuthenticated" } | select InterfaceIndex -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) }
    $Public = $IPAddresses | ? { $_.InterfaceIndex -eq ($Profiles | ? { $_.NetworkCategory -eq "Public" } | select InterfaceIndex -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) }
    if (($Domain -ne $null) -and ($Public -ne $null)) {
        Write-Host "Public Interace on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
    }
    else { Write-Host "None" }
}
else {

    $Adapters = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetEnabled='True'"
    $IPAddresses = @()
    $Profiles = @()
    foreach ($Adapter in $Adapters) {
        $IPAddresses += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index='$($Adapter.Index)'" | Where-Object { $.IPAddress -ne $null -and $.IPSubnet -ne $null -and $.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null }
        $Profiles += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index='$($Adapter.Index)'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
    }
    $Domain = $IPAddresses | ? { $.IPConnectionMetric -lt 50 -and $.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null -and $Profiles[$_.Index - 1] -match "domain" }
    $Public = $IPAddresses | ? { $.IPConnectionMetric -lt 50 -and $.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null -and $Profiles[$_.Index - 1] -match "public" }
    if (($Domain -ne $null) -and ($Public -ne $null)) {
        Write-Host "Public Interace on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "None"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not work and I Don't have Win7 to test this, but here is what I found.

I believe this download will get PowerShell version 5.1 on Windows 7:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Somehow ChatGPT found the old link to Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1), which I believe contains `Get-NetConnectionProfile` cmdlet, **BUT, the link is DEAD:**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Went to the Wayback Machine and gave it the dead link:
https://archive.org/web/

After looking around in the Wayback Machine's history, I found this Feb 21, 2020 page:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200221043944/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Page was for:
**Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)**
Successfully downloaded the 64 bit version of the file (Wouldn't let me download the 32 bit, not sure why.):
`Windows6.1-KB958830-x64-RefreshPkg.msu`------*Size:* **245,285 KB**

If you successfully download and install the above, then you should have PowerShell 5.1 with the `Get-NetConnectionProfile` cmdlet.

Comment: It's not a matter of having PS5.1 - the OS is used for get-netconnectionprofile, as is get-netadapter so I need to replace those calls in the W7 version of this script.

get-netconnectionprofile
get-netconnectionprofile : The term 'get-netconnectionprofile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005

Comment: @dragonspeed, sorry, some of the info I came across indicated that RSAT included get-netconnectionprofile cmdlet, and installing RSAT would make it available.  But I didn't have anything that explicitly said the RSAT for Win7 included that cmdlet.  Sorry if pointing you to trying to install that didn't help.

Comment: No problem.  Appreciate the thought.